# How to filter servercomponent based on a URL query [Next.js, Prisma]

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have the simple goal that when I click on a `CategoryBox`, I want to pass the parameters to my URL and filter my Prisma database based on it.

When I click on a `CategoryBox`, I do get my URL set to example `http://localhost:3000/?category=XYZ`, but no further happens. I do not get my list updated with objects in the category of `XYZ`.

The issue specifically seems to be, that `SearchParams` in `page.tsx` is `undefined`

#### File *src/app/page.tsx*

```
// My main home page (index)
import ClientOnly from "@/app/components/ClientOnly";
import Container from "@/app/components/Container";
import EmptyState from "@/app/components/EmptyState";
import getListings, { IListingsParams } from "@/app/actions/getListings";
import ListingCard from "@/app/components/listings/ListingCard";
import getCurrentUser from "@/app/actions/getCurrentUser";

interface HomeProps {
  SearchParams: IListingsParams;
}

const Home = async ({ SearchParams }: HomeProps) => {
  const listings = await getListings(SearchParams);
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (listings.length === 0) {
    return (
      <ClientOnly>
        <EmptyState showReset />
      </ClientOnly>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ClientOnly>
      <Container>
        <>
          <div
            className="grid">
            {listings.map((listing: any) => {
              return (
                <ListingCard
                  currentUser={currentUser}
                  key={listing.id}
                  data={listing}
                  imageSrcList={listing.imageSrc}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      </Container>
    </ClientOnly>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

#### File *src/app/components/navbar/Categories.tsx*

```
"use client";

import CategoryBox from "../CategoryBox";
import Container from "../Container";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { GiFactory } from "react-icons/gi";

type CategoryType = "A" | "B";

interface CategoriesProps {
  selectedOption: CategoryType;
  visible: boolean;
}

export const categories = {
  A: [
    {
      label: "XYZ",
      icon: GiFactory,
      description: "...",
    },
  ],
  B: [
    {
      label: "ABC",
      icon: GiFactory,
      description: "...",
    },
  ],
};

const Categories: React.FC<CategoriesProps> = ({ selectedOption, visible }) => {
  const params = useSearchParams();
  const category = params?.get("category");
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const isMainPage = pathname === "/";

  if (!isMainPage || !visible) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="pt-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between overflow-x-auto">
        {categories[selectedOption].map((item) => (
          <CategoryBox
            key={item.label}
            label={item.label}
            icon={item.icon}
            selected={category === item.label}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

#### File *src/app/components/CategoryBox.tsx*

```
"use client";

import qs from "query-string";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { IconType } from "react-icons";

interface CategoryBoxProps {
  icon: IconType;
  label: string;
  selected?: boolean;
}

const CategoryBox: React.FC<CategoryBoxProps> = ({
  icon: Icon,
  label,
  selected,
}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const params = useSearchParams();

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    let currentQuery = {};

    console.log("params", params);

    if (params) {
      currentQuery = qs.parse(params.toString());
    }

    const updatedQuery: any = {
      ...currentQuery,
      category: label,
    };

    if (params?.get("category") === label) {
      delete updatedQuery.category;
    }

    const url = qs.stringifyUrl(
      {
        url: "/",
        query: updatedQuery,
      },
      { skipNull: true }
    );

    router.push(url);
  }, [label, router, params]);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={`
        flex
        flex-col
        items-center
        justify-center
        gap-2
        p-3
        border-b-2
        hover:text-neutral-800
        transition
        cursor-pointer
        ${selected ? "border-b-neutral-800" : "border-transparent"}
        ${selected ? "text-neutral-800" : "text-neutral-500"}
      `}>
      <Icon size={26} />
      <div className="font-medium text-sm">{label}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryBox;
```

#### File *src/app/actions/getListings.ts*

```
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";

export interface IListingsParams {
  userId?: string | undefined | null;
  category?: string;
}

export default async function getListings(params: IListingsParams) {
  try {
    const {
      userId,
      category,
    } = params || {};

    let query: any = {};

    if (userId) {
      query.userId = userId;
    }

    if (category) {
      query.category = category;
    }

    const listings = await prisma.listing.findMany({
      where: query,
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: "desc",
      },
    });

    const safeListings = listings.map((listing) => ({
      ...listing,
      createdAt: listing.createdAt.toISOString(),
    }));

    return safeListings;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

I am trying to follow a video tutorial to learn, but I clearly missed something here, that I don't feel I got understood correctly.

But to make it easier to anyone who might feel so, the repository for the tutorial I follow is here:
https://github.com/AntonioErdeljac/next13-airbnb-clone/tree/master

Please note, this is my first next.js CRUD project ever, and it's not clear to me, unfortunately, despite having repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a casing error; the correct prop name is `searchParams`. Update your Home component to the following and try again

```
const Home = async ({ searchParams }: HomeProps) => {
  const listings = await getListings(searchParams);
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  // verify the search params are being passed correctly
  console.log(searchParams);
  
  // ... rest of your code 
  }
export default Home;
```

I took a look at the video tutorial you're following as well and the instructor [uses the correct prop name](https://youtu.be/c_-b_isI4vg?t=27927) in the video - `serachParams`

Comment: I have a mixed feeling of the need to pay you my guts and the feeling of tears, due to two wasted days, trying to understand, not noticing this misspelling at all.. Thank you so endlessly!

Comment: It's always the small things that we miss, glad this got solved for you:) Good luck with the tutorial and congrats on your first Next.js project!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions that are based on typos do not need a full answer.  Just reply via comment.  Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/11810933 - Thanks!